# GDI Device Font in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gdi

I'm writing WPF program (.NET FW 4.5) to show some random text on screen.
More specific I want to use the font supported by a specific printer device to render the text.
Using some pinvoke functions I'm able to enumerate and save all the LOGFONT structure (from GDI).

Following this [example](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/EnumFontFamilies.html) I defined LOGFONT as follow:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct LOGFONT
{
   public Int32 lfHeight;
   public Int32 lfWidth;
   public Int32 lfEscapement;
   public Int32 lfOrientation;
   public Int32 lfWeight;
   public Byte lfItalic;
   public Byte lfUnderline;
   public Byte lfStrikeOut;
   public Byte lfCharSet;
   public Byte lfOutPrecision;
   public Byte lfClipPrecision;
   public Byte lfQuality;
   public Byte lfPitchAndFamily;
  
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = LF_FACESIZE)]
   public String lfFaceName;
}
```

Using the following code I tried to create a System.Drawing.Font object usable by WPF:

```
 try
 {
    System.Drawing.Font newFont = System.Drawing.Font.FromLogFont(selectedLogFontStructure, hdcHandle); //selectedLogFontStructure is the LOGFONT structure obtained using PInvoke GDI
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
    fontInfo.Text = e.Message;
 }
```

When I use a TrueType Font all works but when I select a specific Device font (for example a ZEBRA Font) an exception is thrown:

> Only truetype fonts are supported. This is not a TrueType Font

Is there an alternative way to use Device font with WPF application?

Comment: Haven't researched into WPF much because I hate it with a passion, but GDI+ simply doesn't support all font kinds. Old GDI supports more. Using `System.Drawing.Font` implies GDI+, because the entire System.Drawing namespace is primarily built around GDI+. *However*, I know that it's possible to use GDI font rendering in WPF, but I don't remember any details. You will need to program all drawing code yourself, find out how to get a `HDC` from a WPF graphics object, and use GDI `HFONT` and `DrawTextEx`-derived APIs. I've written a font stack based on that before, but it's all corporate.

Comment: Add.: I assume it is somehow possible to use GDI in WPF because the `TextFormattingMode.Display` option in controls causes text on WPF controls to look like GDI rendering, instead of the default ugly GDI+ rendering. Given that, I assume it's technically possible to use `DrawTextEx`/`HFONT` based APIs with WPF. And given that, your only remaining problem is that you cannot use the `System.Drawing.Font` class, and therefore you cannot use something like `TextRenderer.DrawText`, so you'll have to write that infrastructure yourself. Est. ~500 lines of code for a solid implementation.